# Updating Stock Levels in Magento from a CSV

Tags: php, magento

I have a script that will update the stock quantities in Magento based on matching a SKU. This works fine as long as the headings in the CSV match the fields in Magento they are updating e.g.

sku,qty

ABC123,20

ABC124,20

However my source CSV the headings are named "product id" and "quantity" e.g.

product id,quantity

ABC123,20

ABC124,20

How would I remap the array key name so as the import would work?

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';

 umask(0);
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
 $count = 0;

$file = fopen('/home/public_html/mysite/csvs/my.csv', 'r');

 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

 if ($count == 0) {
 foreach ($line as $key=>$value) {
 $cols[$value] = $key;

 }
 }

 $count++;

 if ($count == 1) continue;

 #Convert the lines to cols
 if ($count > 0) {
 foreach($cols as $col=>$value) {
 unset(${$col});
 ${$col} = $line[$value];

 echo ${$col};
 }
 }

 //print_r($cols); die();

 // Check if SKU exists
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

 if ( $product ) {

 $productId = $product->getId();
 $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
 $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
 $stock = array();

 if (!$stockItemId) {
 $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
 $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
 } else {
 $stock = $stockItem->getData();
 }

 foreach($cols as $col=>$value) {
 $stock[$col] = $line[$value];
 }

 foreach($stock as $field => $value) {
 $stockItem->setData($field, $value?$value:0);
 }



 $stockItem->save();

 unset($stockItem);
 unset($product);
 }

 echo "<br />Stock updated $sku";

 }
 fclose($file);
```

Comment: product ID != SKU and easier to rename in source file?  just open the file and rename

Comment: I cant rename the source file its auto generated by Sage..

Comment: why not you are including it in code just change it with php before you include. And as for other parts of your code you should just join a SKU to your stock collection to avoid the loading of whole product object for each item

Comment: and of course you can just hardcode them in your first foreach :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following article which works great:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-qty-in-magento-in-an-easier-faster-way/

which is simply based on raw sql queries and very fast even for millions of sku's qty updates.

Thanks